# Combining CSV files and splitting the column into 2 columns using R

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I have 40 CSV files with only 1 column each. I want to combine all 40 files data into 1 CSV file with 2 columns.

Data format is like this :

[image: Input data structure]

I want to `split` this column by `space` and combine all 40 CSV files into 1 file. I want to `preserve the number format` as well.

I tried below code but Number format is not fixed and and extra 3rd column added for `Negative` numbers. Not sure why.

**My Code :**

```
 filenames <- list.files(path="C://R files", full.names=TRUE)

 merged <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE)))

 data <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(trimws(merged$V1))," ",fixed=FALSE))

 write.csv(data, "export1.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="NA")
```

T**he output** which i got is as shown below. If you observe, the negative numbers are put into extra column. I just want to split by space and put in 2 columns in the exact number format as in the input.

[image: Output file structure]

**R Output**:

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think your issue might be with Excel, rather than with your R code.

Comment: Thanks @Tim . Number formatting could be related to Excel but not sure about the splitting into 3 columns. The splitting is done by R. I verified the input data, it doesn't have any extra spaces. I think my program is doing something wrong while splitting.

Comment: @Xizam updated my question with R output. Thanks.

Comment: Try splitting by "\t"?

Comment: tried.  "\t" is not splitting at all.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the "merged" data so I can give it a try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121268/discussion-between-venky-and-xizam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the source data is delimited by:

- one space when the second number is negative, and
- two spaces when the second number is positive (space for the absent minus sign).

The trick is to split the string on one ***or more*** spaces:

```
 data <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(trimws(merged$V1))," +",fixed=FALSE))
```

I'm a bit OCD on charsets, unreliable files, etc, so I tend to use splitters such as `"[[:space:]]+"` instead, since it'll catch whitespace-variants instead of the space `" "` or tab `"\t"`.

(In regex-speak, the `+` says "one or more". Other modifiers include `?` as zero or one, and `*` as zero or more.)